# how to determine pattern of cards in 3 Card Game to Find Winner?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, playing-cards

I have created N Three card hands using random sampling from a deck of 52 cards. Now, I want to find winner among the N hands.

These are the rules to find winner.

1. Trial(Three cards with same values)
2. Double Run (Three Cards with values in a sequence and of same suit)
3. Run (Three Cards in a sequence)
4. Color(Three Cards of same suit)
5. Same(two out of three cards have same values)
6. Normal condition

The winning priority of Cards is in descending order and probability of getting these cards is in ascending order.

i.e.

Probability of getting trial is least and winning priority is most and so on.

I have checked in sequence of trial to normal.

```
boolean trial = this.checkTrial();
    if(!trial){
        boolean doubleRun = this.checkDoubleRun();
        if(!doubleRun){
            boolean run = this.checkRun();
            if(!run){
                boolean color = this.checkColor();
                if(!color){
                    boolean same = this.checkSame();
                    if(!same){
                        this.checkHighest();
                        System.out.println("Normal");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Same");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Color");    
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Run");    
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Double Run");    
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Trial");    
    }
```

Is this the best way ?

I have two options
What is the best way to find winning hand among these two ?

- least  to most probability(check from Trial to normal)
- most to least probability(check from normal to trial)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to return the result? Print it out or save it in the appropriate boolean? Is it enough to know what is the best rank or should it know all rules it satisfies?

Comment: I want to save it to an array of boolean values later. There is only one out of six possibilities i.e. mutually exclusive so, if any one of six possible is found then I have to stop.

Comment: And I want to find that possible case in best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you need to build a game system of playing cards with game of 3 card poker or 3 patti or flush,
lets identify all objects involved

1. **Card** - has 2 attribute Color and Cardinality, ergo Class card will be

```
    class Card {

        char color;
        short number;

        public Card(char color, short number) {
            this.color = color;
            this.number = number;

        }

        public char getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(char color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public short getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(short number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
    }
```

2. **Deck**  - Deck is set of 52 cards ,thus

```
    class Deck {

        char[] deckColors = {'♦', '♠', '♣', '♥'};
        short[] cardNum = {(short) 'A', (short) '2', (short) '3', (short) '4', (short) '5', (short) '6', (short) '7',
                           (short) '8', (short) '9', (short) 'T', (short) 'J', (short) 'Q', (short) 'K'};
        int cardCount;

        public Card[] getShuffledDeck() {

            Random r = new Random();


            Card[] deckCards = new Card[(deckColors.length * cardNum.length)];

            int cnt = 0;

            for (char c : deckColors) {
                for (short s : cardNum) {
                    deckCards[cnt++] = new Card(c, s);
                }
            }

            Card[] shuffledDeck = new Card[deckCards.length];

            int addedCount = 0;


            while (addedCount < deckCards.length) {
                int tInt = r.nextInt((deckCards.length));

                Card c = deckCards[tInt];

                if (c != null) {

                    shuffledDeck[addedCount++] = c;
                    deckCards[tInt] = null;

                } else {
                    
                }
            }

            return shuffledDeck;

        }
    }
```

3. **Hand** - set of 3 cards,but its better to have a class created with methods like getHandRanking() which will actually calculate dealt Hand's strength

```
   class Hand {

        Card[] cards;

        int handRank;

        public Hand(Card[] cards) {

            this.cards = new Card[3];

            //sort all cards
            if (cards[0].getNumber() > cards[1].getNumber()) {
                if (cards[0].getNumber() > cards[2].getNumber()) {
                    //0 index is highest card
                    this.cards[2] = cards[0];
                    if (cards[2].getNumber() > cards[1].getNumber()) {
                        //2 is second highest
                        this.cards[1] = cards[2];
                        this.cards[0] = cards[1];
                    } else {
                        //1 is second highest
                        this.cards[1] = cards[1];
                        this.cards[0] = cards[2];
                    }

                } else {
                    //2 index is highest

                    this.cards[2] = cards[2];
                    if (cards[0].getNumber() > cards[1].getNumber()) {
                        //0 is second highest
                        this.cards[1] = cards[0];
                        this.cards[0] = cards[1];
                    } else {
                        //1 is second highest
                        this.cards[1] = cards[1];
                        this.cards[0] = cards[0];
                    }
                }

            } else {
                if (cards[1].getNumber() > cards[2].getNumber()) {
                    //1 index is highest card
                    this.cards[2] = cards[1];
                    if (cards[2].getNumber() > cards[0].getNumber()) {
                        //2 is second highest
                        this.cards[1] = cards[2];
                        this.cards[0] = cards[0];
                    } else {
                        //0 is second highest
                        this.cards[1] = cards[0];
                        this.cards[0] = cards[2];
                    }
                } else {
                    //2 index is highest
                    this.cards[2] = cards[2];
                    if (cards[0].getNumber() > cards[1].getNumber()) {
                        //0 is second highest
                        this.cards[1] = cards[0];
                        this.cards[0] = cards[1];
                    } else {
                        //1 is second highest
                        this.cards[1] = cards[1];
                        this.cards[0] = cards[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public int getHandRank() {
            return handRank > 0 ? handRank : calculateHandRank();
        }

        public int calculateHandRank() {
            //assuming 3 cards dealt
            //Trial - ColorSeq - Seq - Color - Pair
            int[] powerOf2s = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};
            return ((cards[0].getNumber() == cards[1].getNumber() && cards[1].getNumber() == cards[2].getNumber()) ? 1 : 0) * powerOf2s[4]
                    + (((cards[2].getNumber() - 1 == cards[1].getNumber() && cards[1].getNumber() - 1 == cards[0].getNumber()) && (cards[2].getColor() == cards[1].getColor() && cards[1].getColor() == cards[0].getColor())) ? 1 : 0) * powerOf2s[3]
                    + ((cards[2].getNumber() - 1 == cards[1].getNumber() && cards[1].getNumber() - 1 == cards[0].getNumber()) ? 1 : 0) * powerOf2s[2]
                    + (((cards[2].getColor() == cards[1].getColor() && cards[1].getColor() == cards[0].getColor())) ? 1 : 0) * powerOf2s[1]
                    + ((cards[0].getNumber() == cards[1].getNumber() || cards[1].getNumber() == cards[2].getNumber() || cards[0].getNumber() == cards[2].getNumber()) ? 1 : 0) * powerOf2s[0];

        }
    }
```

Now you just need to see which player's hand's rank is highest among all player hands, and if two player happen to have same hand rank then see who has high card in sequence of Hand.cards[2],[1],[0].

let me know if any explanation is required.

the algo can be improved greatly, the given code example is just to show the thought process.

Comment: try to understand what this calculateHandRank() algo is doing, let me know for issues, i'll explain further

Comment: Thanks for your Answer

Comment: I have made all those objects Card Hand and Deck. I have shuffled and distribute 3/3 card to N users already. Your logic seems fine for me. Great !

Comment: great, pl handle sequence case with AKQ , as cardinality of Ace is 1, you need to put check so that AKQ and A23 both are treated vslid sequence and sequence w color.

Comment: I am currently thinking about that AKQ is not a problem but A23 is Really a problem.

Comment: hey, where we are sorting cards in constructor of Hand class, Ace case need to be handled, Ace is highest card individually you Ace cardinality i.e 1 must be handled separately. Further in case of more than 1 player getting sequence, then you just need to check High cards of each player, this way A23 sequence comes above all sequence till KQJ. to keep A23 below 234 rank you need to apply High card check keeping Ace condition handled for seq and color seq.

Comment: yes, I have understand. I have used 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A sequence so QKA is highest but I have to consider A23 as an special case

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean trial, doublerun, run, color, same;
if (this.checkTrial()) {
    trial = true;
}
else if (this.checkDoubleRun() {
    doubleRun = true;
}
else if (...) {
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: I have done similar to this one but is it the best one ?

Comment: At least it is more readable and easier to understand. In a problem this simple, there aren't other criteria, really.

Comment: I don't know too much about optimization. I just want as quick as possible

Comment: @Sagar I know a lot about optimizations and I must say: First, get some clean and simple code. When done, then measure what part takes longest and then optimize. +++ Your case is simple: "Three card hands from a deck of 52 cards" means `52**3 = 140608` possibilities. You may store them all in a table and get sub-microsecond times. +++ Note that it means that the speed of all methods you optimized so far hardly matters as the table gets initialized once only and may be stored to disk (if really needed).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const cardDestribution = (numOfPlayers) => {
  let usedNumbers = "-";
  let randomNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
    //Checking if the random number you get is unique, if you already have it in the string means that this random number is repeated
    while (usedNumbers.includes("-" + randomNumber + "-")) {
      //if a number is repeated, then get a new random number
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
    }
    usedNumbers += randomNumber + "-";
    randomNumbers[i] = randomNumber;
  }
  randomNumbers = randomNumbers.splice(0, 3 * numOfPlayers);
  return randomNumbers.reduce(
    (rows, key, index) =>
      (index % 3 == 0 ? rows.push([key]) : rows[rows.length - 1].push(key)) &&
      rows,
    []
  );
};

const getScore = (cards) => {
  let color = [];
  newCards = cards.map((card) => {
    if (card > 39) {
      color.push(3);
      return card - 39;
    } else if (card > 26) {
      color.push(2);
      return card - 26;
    } else if (card > 13) {
      color.push(1);
      return card - 13;
    } else {
      color.push(0);
      return card;
    }
  });

  newCards = newCards.sort().reverse();

  console.log("Your card:", newCards);
  let score = 0;
  //Colors
  if (color[0] === color[1] && color[1] === color[2]) {
    score = Math.pow(10, 6);
  }
  //Tripple
  if (newCards[0] === newCards[1] && newCards[1] === newCards[2])
    score +=
      Math.pow(10, 8) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[0]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[1]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[2]);
  //Sequence
  else if (newCards[0] - newCards[1] === 1 && newCards[1] - newCards[2] === 1)
    score +=
      Math.pow(10, 7) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[0]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[1]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[2]);
  //Double
  else if (newCards[0] === newCards[1] || newCards[1] === newCards[2]) {
    if (newCards[1] === 1) {
      index = 14;
    } else index = newCards[1];
    score +=
      Math.pow(10, 5) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[0]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[1]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[2]) +
      16338 * index;
  } //Nothing
  else
    score +=
      Math.pow(2, newCards[0]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[1]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[2]);

  //This condtion for RKA
  if (newCards[0] === 13 && newCards[1] === 12 && newCards[2] === 1)
    score +=
      Math.pow(10, 7) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[0]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[1]) +
      Math.pow(2, newCards[2]);
  if (newCards[2] === 1) score += 16338;
  return score;
};

let players = cardDestribution(5);
console.log("Grater Score is winner");
players.map((player) => {
  console.log(player, "\n yourScore is:", getScore(player), "\n\n");
});
```

Comment: Hear is some basic code i write for teen patti game in javascript for fun and hear in sequence QKA is no 1 and A23 is no 2 other is KQJ is no 3 ......etc.

Comment: First, generate 3 cards pair from the 52 cards deck and after 3 card pair have scored so we can make a decision who is the winner. I am a node developer and I need a job if anyone has a vacancy than ask me.